# How can I track a symfony application with github, while not having /web in the directory tree?

Tags: git, symfony

I have build an application with Symfony (v3, if that matters), and I'm tracking the app on GitHub. The `master` branch holds the live version, which means that if any development has been approved, the `staging` branch just has to be merged into the `master` branch and pushed to GitHub. On the live server, I only have to pull the `master` branch, clear the cache, dump assets, and voila! the updated app is live. So far so good.

But as we all know, Symfony demands the `/web` directory to be the document root. This isn't really a big problem, because my beloved host gives me Shell access and allows me to create directories outside my http root. So basically I can put my app in the eg. `/source/` directory and [change the web directory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory) to let it point to `/http_root/`. But how on earth can I still track my app with Git, maintain my extremely simple deployment procedure, and still have the web directory outside of the projects directory, and as such outside of my git repo...?

Comment: Is your web directory in .gitignore? Could it be managed to it be there?

Comment: If you mean if I deliberately change files in the /web directory, nope. I leave that all to symfony and it's friends. So basically, yes I could add it to .gitignore, and let creation of the /web directory be part of the install procedure. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes! And if you put it in gitignore, it would be possible even create a symlink for web directory. Such like that you could put your docroot anywhere in your filesystem!

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep your deployment simple i'd suggest one of two options:

**First option**: Leave your Symfony folder structure inact and point http root to `<symfony_root>/web`

**Second option**: Change Symfony web root to host http root. Please see [Override the web Directory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory)